# Date difference between two locations in same table with one date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Tag will be placed physically in client location and will move around the places. i need find the how long it placed in one location. example if tag is placed in location 1 at 10 am and moved to location 2 at 10:15 then time difference is 15 minutes. here is sample data i have

```
create table #Tagm (tagname varchar(10),created_date datetime ,Loc int )

insert into #Tagm values ('AC1', '2018-07-01 09:35:37.370' ,56)
,( 'AC1', '2018-07-01 10:35:37.370' ,64),( 'AC1', '2018-07-01 10:55:37.370' ,84),( 'AC1', '2018-07-01 11:55:37.370' ,76)
```

I tried this but this is giving me the count for all the locations

```
select tagname ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, min(created_date),max(created_date) )as totaltime 
from #Tagm 
group by tagname
```

the result i am looking for is shown below

[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: thanks for pointing it out , yes it is possible

Comment: because location can be repeated you have to find true start and end times I updated an answer to show you how that can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you mentioned it is possible to have the same Location several times in a row you need to find the true start and end of the time at that location.  By using LAG you can do that similar to one of the other answers.  After finding true start and end then you can grab the difference.  This can be done in less Common Table Expressions or as a subquery but I have split it like this so you can see the logic a bit easier.

I also added a second tagname and the use case that location doesn't change to both.

```
create table #Tagm (tagname varchar(10),created_date datetime ,Loc int )

insert into #Tagm values ('AC1', '2018-07-01 09:35:37.370' ,56), ('AC1', '2018-07-01 09:40:37.370' ,56) ,( 'AC1', '2018-07-01 10:35:37.370' ,64),( 'AC1', '2018-07-01 10:55:37.370' ,84),( 'AC1', '2018-07-01 11:55:37.370' ,76)
insert into #Tagm values ('AC2', '2018-08-01 09:35:37.370' ,56), ('AC2', '2018-08-01 09:40:37.370' ,64) ,( 'AC2', '2018-08-01 10:35:37.370' ,64),( 'AC2', '2018-08-01 10:55:37.370' ,84),( 'AC2', '2018-08-01 11:55:37.370' ,76)

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,LAG(Loc) OVER (PARTITION BY tagname ORDER BY created_date) as PrevLoc
    FROM
       #Tagm
)

, cteLocationStart AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,IIF(PrevLoc IS NULL or PrevLoc <> Loc, 1,0) as StartSequence
    FROM
       cte
)

SELECT 
    s.tagname
    ,s.Loc
    ,s.created_date as StartDateTime
    ,MIN(n.created_date) as EndDateTime
    ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,s.created_date, MIN(n.created_date)) as TotalTime
FROM
    cteLocationStart s
    LEFT JOIN cteLocationStart n
    ON s.tagname = n.tagname
    AND s.created_date < n.created_date
    AND n.StartSequence = 1
WHERE
    s.StartSequence = 1
GROUP BY
    s.tagname
    ,s.Loc
    ,s.created_date
ORDER BY
    tagname
    ,StartDateTime
```

Comment: @user3311323 you are welcome thanks for accepting the answer don't forget to upvote as well if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `lead()`:

```
SELECT tagname,
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
                created_date, 
                LEAD(created_date) OVER (PARTITION BY tagname
                                         ORDER BY created_date
                                        )
              ) AS totaltime
FROM #Tagm t;
```

Comment: @JamesFaix . . . My indentation style is explained in detail in Chapter 1 of my book "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel".  Please don't do me any favors by changing what I write, unless it is to fix an error in the code.

Comment: Didn't mean to offend.  The post came up in the edit approvals queue and I thought it looked odd.

Answer (score 0):

```
with CTE as 
(select  row_number() over (order by created_date desc) as rn, created_date, tagname,loc from #Tagm
)
SELECT t1.loc,t1.created_date, t1.tagname, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(mi, t1.created_date, t2.created_date), NULL) 
AS seconds FROM CTE t1 
LEFT JOIN CTE t2 
ON t1.rn = t2.rn + 1 ORDER BY t1.created_date
```